# select records from a table based on selected column value in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that selects certain column values as a result-set.

Based on some column values resulting from that sub-query, I want to select records from another table.

Eg.

```
POST                   |    Start DATE  |  End DATE   |  MONTHS
---------------------------------------------------------------
Senior Software Engg.  |    2018-04-18  |   -         |
Software Engg.         |    2017-04-18  |  2018-04-18 |  12
Assoc. Software Engg.  |    2016-04-18  |  2017-04-18 |  12
```

I have following result-set from this query:

```
SELECT `POST`, 
    `DATE`,
    IFNULL(END_DATE,'Running') AS END_DATE,
    IFNULL(MONTH,'Running') AS MONTH, user
    FROM
        (
            SELECT `POST`, 
            `DATE`,
            @prev AS END_DATE,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(month,DATE, IFNULL(@prev, CURDATE())) AS MONTH,
            @prev := T.DATE AS VarDate, user
            FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT designation_id as id, d.title as POST, DATE(dt_datetime) as DATE, u.id as user
            FROM users_history_check u
            INNER JOIN
            designations d 
            ON d.id = u.designation_id
            WHERE u.id = $userID
            ORDER BY DATE DESC) T, (SELECT @prev:=null) R
        ) T1
```

I want to fetch records from another table based on `Start DATE` and `END DATE` values in each row.

Expected output:

```
POST                   |    Start DATE  |  End DATE   |  MONTHS |  Team
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Senior Software Engg.  |    2018-04-18  |   -         |  0      | Research
Software Engg.         |    2017-04-18  |  2018-04-18 |  12     | Finance
Assoc. Software Engg.  |    2016-04-18  |  2017-04-18 |  12     | Finance
```

Here's the table from where I want to fetch Team records:

```
user_team

date         |    team       |   users_id
-------------------------------------------------
2016-04-18   |    Finance    |   1
2017-05-18   |    Finance    |   1
2018-04-18   |    Research   |   1
```

How can I do this in a single query?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the relation between the result of your first query and the second table?

Comment: first query generates `Start Date` and `End Date` in each row, based on that those dates, select records with `DATE(date) BETWEEN Start Date AND End Date AND users_id = user`